# How to normal-scale using threejs to make objects 'thicker' or 'thinner'

Tags: math, 3d, three.js

I'm trying to figure out how to extrude an already loaded .obj object to make it "thicker". I think I'm looking for a way to scale my object not from its anchor point but scaling it by each polygon normal.

A classic example would be to take a "ring" object. If you scale it up with just the normal scale methods it just gets bigger from the center but I want the ring to become thicker/thinner. Its called a 'normal scale' in cinema 4d.

Here's some example code of what I currently have, and which isn't giving me the expected result.

```
var objLoader = new THREE.OBJLoader();
var material = new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial({color:'yellow', shading:THREE.FlatShading});
objLoader.load('objects/gun/M1911.obj', function (obj) {
    obj.traverse(function (child) {
      if (child instanceof THREE.Mesh) {
        child.geometry.computeVertexNormals();
        child.material = material;
      }
    });
    obj.material = material;
    obj.scale.set(7, 7, 7);

    scene.add(obj);
});
```

Comment: As you point out, using `obj.scale` will scale the whole object up uniformly from the origin.  To "thicken" an object you need to offset each vertex by some factor (the thickening factor) times its vertex normal.  I'm not familiar enough with three.js to give you a code example but it should be fairly straight forward.  If three.js doesn't have a thicken function, you will need to loop over each vertex and adjust its coordinates.

Comment: I think it doesn't have a thickening function, at least as far as I can see. So yeah, I'm looking for the math or some pointers on how to implement the math. :)

Comment: `v.pos.x += v.norm.x*thicken; v.pos.y += v.norm.y*thicken; v.pos.z += v.norm.z*thicken`

Comment: can't get this to work -yet-. Tried looping over the vertices, they don't have normals, then tried looping over the faces, they have vertices & verticenormals, tried some computations but breaks the whole model apart. Maybe I should just try a vertex shader? (Just being a noob here, but isn't this a good use case to use a shader? :p)

Answer (score 1):

```
scaleGeo: function (geo, ratio) {
    for (var i = 0; i < geo.faces.length; i++) {
        var faceI = geo.faces[i];

        var vertexArr = [faceI.a, faceI.b, faceI.c];
        for (var j = 0; j < vertexArr.length; j++) {
            var vertexJ = geo.vertices[vertexArr[j]];
            var normalJ = faceI.vertexNormals[j];

            if (vertexJ.hasScale) continue;

            vertexJ.x += normalJ.x * ratio;
            vertexJ.y += normalJ.y * ratio;
            vertexJ.z += normalJ.z * ratio;

            vertexJ.hasScale = true;
        }
    }


    return geo;
},
```